# Attempting to unpivot

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm attempting to unpivot a table I have previously created and pivoted and get the error:

> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier" *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 107 Column: 1

Is it to do with the column I'm trying to pivot not being the same datatype as the rows?:

```
select 
sales_per_month, 
Product_id, 
Total_amount 
from pivoted_sales 
unpivot((Total_amount) for (Product_id) in( 
100 as '100', <- 107 
101 as '101',
105 as '105', 
106 as '106',
200 as '200'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `"100" as 100` not `100 as '100'`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/62a65/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE PIVOTED_SALES (
  sales_per_month NUMBER,
  "100" NUMBER,
  "101" NUMBER,
  "105" NUMBER,
  "106" NUMBER,
  "200" NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO pivoted_sales VALUES( 1, 0, 20, 30, 0, 50 );
```

**Query 1**:

```
select  sales_per_month, 
        Product_id, 
        Total_amount 
from pivoted_sales 
unpivot(
  Total_amount for Product_id in( 
    "100" as 100,
    "101" as 101,
    "105" as 105, 
    "106" as 106,
    "200" as 200
  )
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/62a65/1/0)**:

```
| SALES_PER_MONTH | PRODUCT_ID | TOTAL_AMOUNT |
|-----------------|------------|--------------|
|               1 |        100 |            0 |
|               1 |        101 |           20 |
|               1 |        105 |           30 |
|               1 |        106 |            0 |
|               1 |        200 |           50 |
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `"` instead of `'` in the `unpivot` columns name.

```
select 
sales_per_month, 
Product_id, 
Total_amount 
from pivoted_sales 
unpivot(Total_amount for Product_id in( 
"100",
"101",
"105", 
"106",
"200"))
```